# Delete Rule Cascade on Core Data 3 entities relation

Tags: objective-c, core-data, cascade

I have a relation with 3 entities in my Core Data model with the next relation A<<---->B<<---->C.

When A object is deleted B must be deleted if there is no more A in the A<<--->B relation, and C must be deleted if there is no more B in the B<<--->C relation.

I tried to configure the relation with:

First option:

- A to B relation is "to one" and Deletion Rule is "Cascade"
- B to A relation is "to many" and Deletion Rule is "Nullify"
- B to C relation is "to one" and Deletion Rule is "Cascade"
- C to B relation is "to many" and Deletion Rule is "Nullify"
  In this case when I delete an A entity B and C are always deleted no matter there are more entities.

Second option:

- A to B relation is "to one" and Deletion Rule is "Cascade"
- B to A relation is "to many" and Deletion Rule is "Deny"
- B to C relation is "to one" and Deletion Rule is "Cascade"
- C to B relation is "to many" and Deletion Rule is "Deny"
  In this case there is a exception and there is no action.

Third option:

I tried to use prepareForDeletion with this example code in B:

```
- (void) prepareForDeletion {
    [super prepareForDeletion];

    EntityC *entityC = self.entityC;
    if (entityC && (entityC.isDeleted == NO)) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isDeleted == NO"];
        NSSet *setOfBs = [entityC.Bs filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];

        if ([setOfBs count] == 0) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:entityC];
        }
    }
```

In this last case I have a random result. Sometimes it works as I expect and sometimes I only delete A entity.

Is there any simple way to solve this problem. I'd prefer to use a solution like First or Second one, but I think is only possible using a solution like the third one.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what the relation is between A B and C is it A to many B and B to many C and C to one B and B to one A? If so, try with cascade delete rule across the board.

Comment: No, is A to one B, B to one C and C to many B, B to many A. If I use cascade everything is deleted even if B has more As.

Comment: OK I see now. It's the opposite to what I thought. I think that you're going to have to programatically check the relation upon delete. As far as I know there's no delete upon empty relationship rule. When an A is deleted, get the B that it relates to and check the B for more A's then delete the B appropriately.